# Why Tensorflow doesn't show output nodes for Constant Ops but shows them for Variable Ops?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently learning TensorFlow using [TensorFlow for Machine Intelligence](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/tensorflow-for-machine/9781939902351/). I am executing the following code -

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.Variable([1,2,3], name="input_a")
b = tf.Variable([2,3,4], name="input_b")
c = tf.multiply(a,b, name="mul_c")
d = tf.add(a,b, name="add_d")
e = tf.add(c,d, name="add_e")
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(a.initializer)
sess.run(b.initializer)
output = sess.run(e)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./my_graph', sess.graph)
writer.close()
sess.close()
```

I get the following output at TensorBoard -

[image: Variable 1]

The details of the highlighted node are -

[image: Variable 2]

On the other hand, if the values of `a` and `b` are changed to the following -

`a = tf.constant([1,2,3], name="input_a"); b = tf.constant([2,3,4], name="input_b")` and appropriate changes are made to the Session code, the following output is shown -

[image: Constant 1]

The following output is shown in TensorBoard -

[image: Constant 2]

Why is the `Variable node` having `Output nodes` but `Constant node` doesn't have them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.Operation` represents a graph node and performs computation on tensors. `tf.constant` returns a special kind of `tf.Operation` which takes 0 tensors as input and produces 0 tensors as output since it performs no computation.

While `tf.Variable` is in fact a nested operation (or subgraph) consists of 3 nodes. Double click the variable subgraph in tensorboard you will see:
[image]

It starts with a constant (e.g. `initial_value` which is highlighted), writes its value to device memory and reads value to feed to its consumers.

---

EDIT for question in comment:

To my understanding, when users call this method, say, `a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3], name='input_a')`, two things will happen in different aspects:

1. a `Const` node will be added to computation graph as you can see in the 3rd image you provided. Its exact value is known at graph construction time but (I guess) it's not callable in the underlying implementation. Thus tensorboard says this node has no inputs and **outputs**. Maybe this node is just like a pointer pointing to the corresponding device memory with its value, waiting for other callable nodes to find it.
2. a `Constant Tensor` will be **returned** and you can use it using its handler `a` later, e.g. `c = tf.multiply(a, b, name="mul_c")` as you did.

So '**return**' means returning a handler in Python by a Python method while '**outputs**' (in tensorflow computation graph) lists all the consumers of a callable node's output.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I checked the documentation for tf.constant, it was showing that it returns a constant tensor. At the risk of sounding extremely silly, isn't returning a value same as outputting it?

Comment: Actually it's a good question. I've edited my answer and hope it can help you :D

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. It is very helpful. However, if you don't mind, I will hold on to accepting this answer to see if are any more authoritative answers.